# OpenLayers can't get feature by key, undefined error

Tags: methods, get, openlayers

I am trying to get some key values from features in extent but I am unable to.

I tried to look up ID [feature.getId()] which works totally fine, see here:

[image]

If I try feature.get('id') it's **undefined** for some reason. (And it's undefined for every key I am trying to get by name)

I tried feature.getKeys() and it's returning geometry,**info**,index,popup.

I stored every info I need under info key.

I tried to get data in console and I can see that a point has 'id' key, and I am unable to get it with feature.get('id')

[image]

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should use `feature.getId()`

Comment: I tried, but I need to get other key values besides ID. For example I need value of key 'status'

Answer (score 1):

I had to access values with Object.values method.

Object.values(Object.values(feature.get("info"))[0][2])[1]